# How can int datatype store a NUMBER(10) field of oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, integer

I am working on a java project and using oracle as a database. There is a field called timeout in a table which is of the size NUMBER(10).
In the existing code, we are storing it in an int type variable. 
Considering that NUMBER(10) can range up to 9,999,999,999 i.e, 9 billion and int can store maximum value of 2,147,483,647 i.e, 2.1 billion, it is not advisable to use long?

Comment: That depends on whether you'll be using timeouts longer than ~24 days (assuming the timeout is in milliseconds).

Comment: It's better to switch to `long` to avoid issues with values too big for `int`. But if possible values in that column are somehow limited (trigger in database or application uses property of type `int` to store values in that column) then you can continue to use `int`

Comment: What is the application requirement for that value? You won't be able to put a value larger than 2.1 billion in that column from your Java application if it's sending an int, which may be more than enough for a timeout. Someone could put a larger value in manually and then your application would have a problem retrieving it, I suppose; if there is no check constraint on the column, which is something you could verify. If the column was `number(9)` then you couldn't fit all int values in any more.

Comment: "... it is not advisable to use long?" - no, it is not. LONG datatype (if that's what you are talking about) shouldn't be used any more *at all*; nowadays it exists only for backward compatibility.

Comment: @Littlefoot he's talking about `long`, as they're currently using `int`.

Comment: That's what I understood, yes, @Kayaman. Though, my comment is irrelevant if the OP talks about **Java** datatypes (which I know nothing about), as I was referring to Oracle ones. I was fooled by the "oracle" tag, I presume.

Comment: @Kayaman: the confusion arises because of the different uses of 'long/LONG'. In Java 'long' is a 64-bit integer datatype. In Oracle 'LONG' is an obsolete BLOB-like datatype. This has tripped up more than one person who is only familiar with one of the definitions. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis yup, seems like the tags invited a mixed group and the result is confusion :)

Comment: @Littlefoot From long I mean long datatype of Java

Comment: Right. I can't help, but I hope someone else will. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be using `BigDecimal` for the value.